# Carriage Return / Linefeed Duplicate Item - Duplicate Component names under same folder

Tags: core-service, cme, 2013-sp1

When importing content into Tridion via core services, has anyone ever seen duplicates of the same item? I've been working with Tridion for a bit now, and I have not seen this happen in the UI or in CS.

[image]

I am wondering if it's a bug or if it was allowed since different users have been running the core service import tool (homegrown tool)? For example, one under your account and another under an SDLT admin account..

Or if the tool was ran locally prior and is on a server now?

Also, once the 2 items that are named the same are under the same folder, through the UI I am able to make a change and save + close the items successfully..

**UPDATE**

The webdav for both components named exactly the same, returns a

[image]

2 web dav urls - I notice on the url that is marked - 'not working below', in the end there is something funny **%0D%0A**-shortDescription.xml, which returns a 400 error, but if I remove the **%0D%0A** then it returns a 401 Server Error - I think which we would expect to see..

%0D%OA means there are carriage return linefeed characters in the name from the service..

Working

`http://somerandomsite.com/webdav/040%20abc%20Content%20(en-US)/Building%20Blocks/Content/Something%20-%20abc/some-thing/Some-Types/Garden%20Pool%20Wing%20-%201%20bedroom%20Suite%20-%20Club%20Level-shortDescription.xml`

Not working

`http://somerandomsite.com/webdav/040%20abc%20Content%20(en-US)/Building%20Blocks/Content/Something%20-%20abc/some-thing/Some-Types/Garden%20Wing%20-%20Hospitality%20Suite%20Access%0D%0A-shortDescription.xml`

Has anyone ever run into this before?

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue in your core service tool - if you try to see it with Magnifying glass - the two names looks a bit different to me- focus on the dash (-) - the two dash in the two same named component looks a bit different to me at least in the screen shot. Can you try just open and save & close without making a change - I hope it won't let you do that.

Comment: there are 3 names above. 2 that look identical to me - I keep starring to see a difference, zooming in etc.. Ill keep looking :) and one that I renamed `_renamed` for reference..

Comment: @PankajGaur Yes. I can open save and close it, works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AS per Pankaj's comment it's likely to be the encoding of one of the characters (usually the hyphen).

Right click the components (one at a time) and select to open using WebDAV; compare the URL encoded path and you'll likely see there will be a slight difference.

### UPDATE

Just so it doesn't get missed - wanted to promote the comment made by Andrew that clarifies this could be a bug slipping through when creating items through the core server:

> We suspect that this is a tridion bug - since core service supports
>   carriage line feed return via webdav url, but it does NOT support it
>   within the name field insert (on content import from service), so it
>   makes it pass the 'uniqueness' test of all names need to be unique
>   within a folder. This allows for you to add duplicate items.. I can
>   open a component and the name has no spaces at all. For example, I can
>   copy one of the dupicate entries and paste it 100x.. try me, already
>   did it 18x :) .If someone finds this in the future, we are stripping
>   the carriage return on the service import.

Comment: Neither of the 2 components WebDAV url is working..

Comment: 'Bad Request - Invalid URL'  even when I delete one of the 2 with the same name, still doesn't work.

Comment: We suspect that this is a tridion bug - since core service supports carriage line feed return via webdav url, but it does NOT support it within the name field insert (on content import from service), so it makes it pass the 'uniqueness' test of all names need to be unique within a folder. This allows for you to add duplicate items.. I can open a component and the name has no spaces at all. For example, I can copy one of the dupicate entries and paste it 100x.. try me, already did it 18x :) .If someone finds this in the future, we are stripping the carriage return on the service import.

Comment: `select * from items where title like '%'||chr(10)||'%';` That query will tell us what are the contents that cause duplicate content(same name in folder) issues..